# Kendo grid does not let me filter columns when using custom column template

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've got this kendoGrid which is using some custom templates for the columns. I have the filterable tag set to true, but the filter only shows up under the Name column, and not under any of the columns using the custom template. Can anyone show me how I can filter these columns while using a custom column template?

```
filterable: true,
columns: [
       { field: "Name", title: "Name", width: "100px" },
       { template: kendo.template($("#SiteAccess-template").html()), title: "Site access", filterable: true },
       { template: kendo.template($("#EmployeeStatus-template").html()), title: "Employee status", width: "100px", filterable: true },
```

My template, if you need to see it:

```
<script id="EmployeeStatus-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
# if (IsClearedEmployee) {#
    Cleared Employee, 
#} if (IsEmployee) {#
    Employee 
#}#</script>
```

Comment: Can you put the complete code.

Comment: is your code the same http://dojo.telerik.com/@harsh/EHIQE

Answer (score 0):

To enable the filter on a column, you have to specify the field for that column.

See sample http://jsbin.com/yekabi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Yes that is required but he is trying to use different fields for a single column template.

Comment: My field is a template, I've got the potential for two fields to be listed in the same column. I do not understand.

Comment: Unless you define a field on the column, built in filtering will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below to help sort any custom template column.

This is a workaround I was able to write in AngularJS after researching for many days.

```js
sortable: {
    compare: function (a, b) {
        return  sortCustomTemplate(a, b, gridName);
    }
},

function sortCustomTemplate(a, b, gridName) {
    let grd = $("#" + gridName).data("kendoGrid");
    if (grd) {
        const field = grd.dataSource.sort()[0]["field"];
        const orignaltemp = grd["columns"].find(x => x['field'] === field)["template"];

        const aTemp = orignaltemp.replace(/dataItem/g, `a`);
        const bTemp = orignaltemp.replace(/dataItem/g, `b`);

        const aTemplate = kendo.template(aTemp);
        const bTemplate = kendo.template(bTemp);
        
        $('#' + gridName).append('<div type="hidden" id ="aDiv"></div>');
        $('#' + gridName).append('<div type="hidden" id ="bDiv"></div>');
        
        $("#aDiv").html(aTemplate({ field: a[field] }));
        $("#bDiv").html(bTemplate({ field: b[field] }));
        
        var nameA = eval($("#aDiv").text()).toUpperCase();
        var nameB = eval($("#bDiv").text()).toUpperCase();
        
        $("#aDiv").remove();
        $("#bDiv").remove();
        
        if (nameA < nameB) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (nameA > nameB) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```